# Resolve equation with bisection method in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I want to create a function that resolve an equation by using the bisection method, but all I get is the wrong answer:

```
%declaire function
function c=dichotomie(f,a,b,n)
fa=f(a);
fb=f(b);
error=abs(fa-fb);
while(error<n )
         if(fb==0)
         c=fb;
         elseif(fa==0)
          c=fa;
          break;
         elseif(fa<0)
        fb=f(c);
        elseif(fb<0)
        fa=f(c);
    end
    c=(a+b)/2; 
   error=abs(fa-fb);
         end
end
%call the function
syms x
f=inline('x+1');
m=-1;s=3;l=0.1;
D=dichotomie(f,m,s,l);
D
```

Comment: Do it by hand: 1st iteration, fa=f(-1)=0, fb=f(3)=4,errors=abs(fa-fb)=4 and n=0.1 so your condition `while(error < n)` is false and the function terminates.

Comment: you want to iterate **until** the error is smaller than a threshold, not **while** the error is smaller than a theshold